# Jest + JavaScript ES Modules

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, es6-modules, babel-jest

I've built a command-line tool in JavaScript. I want to write tests for it. I thought of Jest as the first option.

I'm getting the following error when running the tests:
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

#### Here's what I've tried:

- I've installed Jest and its dependencies via `npm install --save-dev jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-jest`
- I created a `babel.config.cjs` file with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }]],
};
```

- I've updated the following sections in my `package.json`:

```json
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    }
  },
```

- My tests are inside of a `__tests__` folder, and the test files have the following naming convention `fileName.test.js`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable experimental support for ES modules. Try the following in your `package.json`, instead of simply `jest`:

```
NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-vm-modules' jest
```